# Two-component separable prefixes in German: What are they called in German?

Tags: single-word-request, terminology, prefix

There are names in German for separable prefixes (*trennbare Präfixe*) and  inseparable prefixes (*nicht trennbare Präfixe*). Prefixes that can be either separable or inseparable are descriptively called *Präfixe, die sowohl trennbar als auch nicht trennbar sind*.

Is there a term in German to describe a two-component separable prefix? One example of a verb with such a prefix is:

> miteinbeziehen |bezog **mit ein** / miteinbezogen|

Comment: Interesting question. I wasn't even aware, that such multi-prefix separable verbs exists.

Comment: There can't be many of them, can there? I am not aware of a special term for that (and, to be honest, like Hubert wasn't even aware of the phenomenon until now.)

Comment: @Ingmar I think I saw 3 or 4 such verbs during the past 34 months of reading German newspapers. I managed to find one more verb with a two-component separable prefix in my word list: mitansehen |sah mit an, mitangesehen|. However, the word is not included in the Duden, only in dict.cc and Reverso Dictionary.

Comment: There's actually quite some of them, but I doubt they have a name on their own. *beinhalten*, *beeindrucken*, *bevorstehen*, *mitansehen*, *vernachlässigen*,...

Comment: @tofro: »beinhalten« ist kein trennbares Verb (gilt auch für einige andere deiner Beispiele). Zukunft: »Ich werde das morgen **mitansehen**. Das Glas wird morgen Wasser **beinhalten**.« Vergangenheit: »Ich **sah** das gestern **mit an**. Das Glas **hielt** gestern Wasser **be in**???« Wohl eher: »Das Glas **beinhaltete** gestern Wasser.«

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Danke - nicht richtig gelesen...

Comment: Are there any other extra prefixes that behave like this other than 'mit'? The phenomenon might not have a name.

Comment: @KilianFoth: Yes. they are some other, albeit very few. But _weiter_ (e.g. _weiteransprechen_) is the only one coming to my mind right now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer your question of the headline first: You are searching for the German word ***Doppelpartikelverben*** (in English, you could use *double phrasal verbs* or *double particle verbs,* but as they don’t exist in the English language, there is no official term).

### Some precision to your question (and this answer)

Your explanation and comparison of prefixes is only half correct as you assume that all syllables before the verb are prefixes, but some of them are called particles (in German *Partikel*).

**Prefixes** are non-dividable and aren’t words for themselves (as a big difference to particles; e.g. *be-*, *ver-*). Linguists assume that they originate from prepositions.

**Particles** are words, which are also real German words for themselves (e.g. *über*, *durch*, which can also be prepositions and adverbs; *über* is is in addition to this adjective).

#### Inseparable prefixes

What you called inseparable prefixes can be prefixes in the narrower sense (*Präfixverben* or *prefix verbs*) as a verb with a prefix. But they can also be verbs with a particle in front of the verb (*Partikelpräfixverben*; in English, I would suggest *particle-prefix verbs*). The particle of the latter ones are treated as a prefixes (complicated, huh?).

Both compound verbs have their phonetical accent on the verb itself (and not the particle/prefix).

#### Separable *prefixes*

They are called phrasal or particle verbs (*Partikelverben* in German) and have a particle in front of the verb.

If the word has two particles, then it's called *Doppelpartikelverb*. You can’t find words with more than two particles in the German language. **But** not all these verbs are separated into three single words in the [verb second word order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2_word_order). (Maybe, this is historical, because people are lazy and forgot the space between the two particles over the decades, but this is a blind guess.)

The phonetical accent is on the particle (the second, if you have two).

#### Prefixes that can be either separable or inseparable

This is a help for people learning German, as these verbs are either particle-prefix verbs (the separable) or phrasal verbs (the inseparable).

#### How to decide, which one it is?

You can distinguish between a prefix and a particle by considering whether the prefix/particle can be a word itself. A particle can; a prefix cannot. If you’re not certain, you could use some (incomplete) lists (e.g. [the German Wikipedia’s one](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4fix#Verbalpr.C3.A4fixe)).

To distinguish between a particle-prefix and a phrasal verb, you can test the morphological separability (*morphologische Trennbarkeit*):

- Try to build the infinitive with *zu*. If it is possible within the verb (like in *Sie hat vor, aufzustehen*), then it's a particle verb. If not (like in *Sie hat vor, überzustehen*), then it's a particle-prefix verb.
- Or you can build the past participle (*Partizip II*): If the syllable *ge* is possible within the verb (like in *aufgestanden*), then it's a particle verb, else (maybe) not.
  In some odd cases, this can only be a positive check, cause when it’s not possible (like in your example *miteinbezogen*). Then you have to rely on the other test.

If you have a good feeling for German language or have a German native speaker available, you can go by accent when pronouncing the word (or upon the context).

The University of Leipzig has a [neat and short summary](http://www.uni-leipzig.de/~asw/ggs/Handouts/Oehl.pdf) with lots of examples and some tests; unfortunately, in German.

### Sources

- [Linguistic tutorial of the Technical University of Berlin [German]](http://fak1-alt.kgw.tu-berlin.de/call/linguistiktutorien/morphologie/morphologie%20k4.html#bildv)
- [Dissertation about prefix and phrasal verbs in the German Finnish contrast [German]](https://helda.helsinki.fi/bitstream/handle/10138/19263/prafixun.pdf?sequence=2) (and its sources)
- [Semantics of the verb prefix *ver-* in modern German and its equivalents in the Serbian language [German]](http://epub.ff.uns.ac.rs/index.php/gff/article/download/809/819)
- [Semantic power of prefixes in German verbs [German]](http://is.muni.cz/th/146054/ff_b/Semantische_Leistung_der_Prafixe_bei_deutschen_Verben.doc)
- Altmann, Hans; Kemmerling, Silke: Wortbildung fürs Examen, Göttingen 2005 ([partially available online](https://books.google.de/books?id=I9SSr9ufL1MC&lpg=PA90&ots=HDKvvXh1Kk&dq=doppelpartikelverben%20zur%C3%BCck&hl=de&pg=PA88#v=onepage&q=doppelpartikelverben%20zur%C3%BCck&f=false)). pp 88-90

Apparently, I have no English sources, as this construct doesn’t exist in the English language.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I am aware there is no such thing as you are describing. @biolauri suggested the term **Doppelpartikelverb**, but it is actually a term originating from the field of Morphologie, which isn't applicable.

> **Partikelverb**: syntactically seperable; verb elements for a verbal "bracket", where the left sentence bracket is occupied by the finite verb stem and the right sentence bracket is occupied by the particle. *zu* in the infinitive form is word-internal, as is *ge-* in participle form.
>
> Examples:
>
> - umgefahren, "Er fährt ihn um."
> - heimgehen, "Er geht heim."

This looks like what your supposed "two-component seperable prefix" indicates.

> **Doppelpartikelverb**: Behaves like a Partikelverb, but has a "double particle" (**not** two particles).
>
> Examples:
>
> - hineingehen (**hin**+**ein**+gehen), "Er geht in das Geschäft hinein."
> - hinterherfahren (**hinter**+**her**+fahren), "Wir fahren ihr hinterher."

On first glance you think this would be a representation of what you're looking for, but in (nearly) all cases, this double-particle is non-seperable. In fact, your mentioned example formed with *mit* is the *only* example I have ever seen, where the double-particle (I am not even sure that it is or isn't a double-particle) is seperated.

It very well may be, that when a particle is formed with "mit" there is a special rule that the seperated particle is seperated between the two components. I can not find a rule for this, but it's a very specific case, so that may not mean anything.

All in all I have to agree with @Janka in that the category you envision isn't defined and there is likely only an implicit rule for it. Additionally, his/her description of the difference between inseperable prefixes and particles is sound.

An additional comment regarding the morphological seperability check that @biolauri suggests:

Don't try to check for the applicability of *ge-* in the past participle. Rather check for strong, mixed or weak verb, (check how often the [stem vowel changes](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/starke-und-schwache-verben)), which is a better indicator for morphological seperability, albeit also not without exception.

Answer (score -3):

The categories are about the prefixes, not about the words having those prefixes.

The difference between inseparable prefixes and separable ones is fundamental. Inseparable prefixes like *be-*, *ent-*, *ver-* and *zer-* aren't words —not even particles—, while separable are.

There are even mixed words, e.g.

> (sich) vorbereiten → Sie bereitete sich vor.
>
> vorverlegen → Man verlegte die Prüfung vor.

So, no, there isn't a special category needed for words with more than one prefix.

Note there is a small category of inseparable prefixes *which are words*. Most prominent examples are **über** und **unter**.

> überweisen → Die Ärztin überwies ihn ins Krankenhaus.
>
> unterweisen → Sie unterwies ihn.
>
> unternehmen → Er unternahm etwas.
>
> unter**stel**len → Sie unterstellte ihm eine Affäre.

BUT

> **un**terstellen → Er stellte sein Fahrrad unter.

**unter** can be both, separable and inseparable. Note the stress for the inseparable prefixed word is different from the separable prefixed one.

Comment: Ich kann nicht erkennen, wo du auf jene Wörter eingehst, die zwei Silben/Wörter abspalten wenn sie geteilt werden. z.B. mitansehen. Zukunft: »Ich werde das morgen **mitansehen**.« Vergangenheit: »Ich **sah** das gestern **mit an**.« Der Fragesteller bezog sich ja nicht allgemein auf Verben mit zwei Vorsilben, sondern auf trennbare Verben, bei beim Trennen gleich zwei Silben abspalten.

Comment: Im ersten Beispiel und der Schlussfolgerung. Die Frage bezog sich bereits darauf, ob es eine besondere Ordnung von Worten gibt, die zwei Präfixe besitzen. Nein, die gibt es nicht, weil das für den Satzbau unerheblich ist. Die bekannte, vom OP zitierte Einordnung bezieht sich schließlich auf die Präfixe selbst, nicht auf die Worte, die sie enthalten.

Comment: Ich habe vorneweg noch einen Satz ergänzt.

Comment: Im ersten Beispiel spaltet das Verb nur ein Wort ab. Fiele es tatsächlich in die Menge jener Verben, nach denen der OP gefragt hat, sähe dein Beispiel so aus: »(sich) **vorbereiten** → Sie **ritt** sich **vor be**.« Das ist aber natürlich falsch. Vergleiche mit: »(etwas) **mitansehen** → Sie **sah** etwas **mit an**.« Der OP hat nach genau solchen Beispielen gefragt, diese werden in deiner Antwort aber nicht thematisiert.

Comment: Die Frage bezieht sich auch ausdrücklich auf »Two-component separable prefixes«, Also auf »zweiteilige **abspaltbare** Präfixe«. Nicht auf »Trennbare Verben mit zwei Präfixen.« Der Unterschied: In einem Fall (nämlich dem, nach dem gefragt wird) müssen beide Silben/Wörter abspaltbar sein, im anderem Fall (nämlich dem, auf den du eingegangen bist) ist das aber nicht notwendig.

Comment: Es geht bei der bekannten, vom OP zitierten Kategorisierung um die Präfixe. Es geht dabei nicht um die Worte, die diese Präfixe führen. Die Frage, welcher Kategorie *Worte, die zwei abtrennbare Präfixe führen* angehören ist wenig sinnvoll, denn es gibt bereits schon keine Kategorie der *Worte, die ein Präfix führen*. Das sind einfach viel zu viele Worte aus zu vielen unterschiedlichen Wortarten.

Comment: @Janka As the person who asked the question, I'd like to support Hubert Schölnast in this discussion. Your answer does not address "two-component separable prefixes", an example of which would be "bezog mit ein".

Comment: @Eugene Str.: You ask for a category that doesn't exist. There isn't such thing as a "two-component separable prefix" as there isn't such thing as a "two-component prefix" already. These are made-up categories which serve no purpose. You don't need them, you don't need a name for them. The only important difference you need to be aware of is inseparable vs. separable.

Comment: @Janka: 'There isn't such thing as a "two-component separable prefix" as there isn't such thing as a "two-component prefix" already.' - the example from the question, *miteinbeziehen*, would seem to prove this statement wrong. You may claim that you know no name for this particular kind of verbs, but the claim that it does not exist is simply not true.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: There is no category for such "prefixes". Because it's not a "two-component" prefix but two prefixes. There isn't a word *mitein*, but only the words *mit* and *ein*. That's why it reads *Er bezog sie mit ein* and not *Er bezog sie mitein*. A word as *miteinbeziehen* isn't categorized as having a "two-component" prefix either, because it grammatically makes no sense. The only categorization needed is separable vs. inseparable.

Comment: @Janka: "A word as *miteinbeziehen* isn't categorized as having a 'two-component' prefix either, because it grammatically makes no sense." - fine. Then it's categorized as having two separable prefixes instead of just one. "The only categorization needed is separable vs. inseparable." - "needed" for what purpose? If we want to distinguish verbs from which one prefix separates for some forms from verbs from which two prefixes separate, obviously the categorization "separable vs. inseparable" is useless, and another categorization is needed.

Comment: @O. R. Mapper: the purpose is grammar. Inseparable prefixes stick to the verb while separable ones go to the end of the clause. That's a fundamental difference. Your made-up category serves no purpose other than having a long list of otherwise unconnected words which happen to have more than one separable prefix. You don't need that list for anything. You don't need a list of "two-component" prefixes either. You only have to spot the simple prefixes and know whether they are separable or inseparable (or both).

Comment: @Janka: "You don't need that list for anything. You don't need a list of 'two-component' prefixes either." - grammar exercises about embedding verbs in sentences could be grouped to start with the simplest (inseparable prefixes), then getting more difficult (only one separable prefix first), then getting even harder (two separable prefixes). A language analysis software might have to distinguish sentence structures by single separable prefixes and two separable prefixes. I can think of various possible purposes for that categorization that have nothing to do with "having a long list".

Comment: Now you're talking seriously. Seriously?

Comment: @Janka: Sorry, you just lost me there :S No idea what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: I placed a bounty on that question. Please see over there.